# SQL server select data from XML file

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have xml file that looks like so :

```
<claim:ProviderClaim xmlns:claim="http://schemas.phisc.org.za/draft/claim" xmlns:ccts="http://schemas.phisc.org.za/draft/document" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<claim:ReferenceInfo>
<claim:Provider id="1">
<claim:CommonProviderInfo>
<claim:RegistrationNumber typeOfBody="PCNS">5807824</claim:RegistrationNumber>
<claim:PCNSNumber>5807824</claim:PCNSNumber>
</claim:CommonProviderInfo>
<claim:Name>Mediclinic Morningside</claim:Name>
</claim:Provider>
<claim:Provider id="2">
<claim:CommonProviderInfo>
<claim:RegistrationNumber typeOfBody="HPCSA">0620000323624</claim:RegistrationNumber>
<claim:PCNSNumber>0620000323624</claim:PCNSNumber>
</claim:CommonProviderInfo>
<claim:FullName>
<claim:Initials>none</claim:Initials>
<claim:Surname>DR SULEMAN YF</claim:Surname>
</claim:FullName>
</claim:Provider>
<claim:Diagnosis id="1">
<claim:DiagnosisCode role="PRIMARY" schema="ICD-10" isAuthorisationPrimary="No">K04.6</claim:DiagnosisCode>
<claim:DiagnosisCode role="SECONDARY" schema="ICD-10" isAuthorisationPrimary="No">K08.8</claim:DiagnosisCode>
<claim:DiagnosisCode role="COMORBIDITY" schema="ICD-10" isAuthorisationPrimary="No">E14.9</claim:DiagnosisCode>
<claim:DiagnosisCode role="COMORBIDITY" schema="ICD-10" isAuthorisationPrimary="No">I10</claim:DiagnosisCode>
</claim:Diagnosis>
</claim:ReferenceInfo>
```

I am trying to query it with :

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM #XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML , '<claim xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'



SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'ProviderClaim/ReferenceInfo/Provider')
WITH 
(
    id   [varchar](50) '@id'

)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

But the results is empty - how do query this xml ? I think it has something to do with the claim: namespace.

Thanks

Comment: The provided XML is incomplete - it is missing the closing `</claim:ProviderClaim>` element.

Comment: Aside... generally avoid `OPENXML()` as it's too easy to leak resources by forgetting to release them via `sp_xml_removedocument`. This is something even most Microsoft examples forget to do on `learn.microsoft.com`. :( Prefer to use the XQuery methods [`query()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/query-method-xml-data-type), [`nodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/nodes-method-xml-data-type) and [`value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML the namespaces matter:

- the element `<Foo />` is in the anonymous namespace.
- the element `<Foo xmlns="urn:example" />` is in the `urn:example` namespace.
- the element `<bar:Foo xmlns:bar="urn:example" />` is also in the `urn:example` namespace.
- `<Foo />` and `<Foo xmlns="urn:example" />` are both named `Foo`, but they exist in different namespaces so they are not equivalent.

This means you need to declare the correct namespaces when you wish to query elements - the prefixes don't matter, the namespaces they reference do.

If you use `OPENXML` to query your document that would look like this:

```sql
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML , '<fooPrefix:ProviderClaim xmlns:fooPrefix="http://schemas.phisc.org.za/draft/claim"/>';
SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/fooPrefix:ProviderClaim/fooPrefix:ReferenceInfo/fooPrefix:Provider', 1)
WITH 
(
    id   [varchar](50) '@id'
);
EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc;
```

Or using modern XQuery methods:

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(
  'http://schemas.phisc.org.za/draft/claim' as fooPrefix
)
SELECT Provider.value(N'@id', N'int') as [id]
FROM @xml.nodes('/fooPrefix:ProviderClaim/fooPrefix:ReferenceInfo/fooPrefix:Provider') ReferenceInfo(Provider);
```

Both queries return the results:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Answer (score 1):

As AlwaysLearning says in the comments, you better don't make use of `OPENXML`

This might give you a good start for using XQuery:

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML;

SET @XML = '<claim:ProviderClaim xmlns:claim="http://schemas.phisc.org.za/draft/claim" xmlns:ccts="http://schemas.phisc.org.za/draft/document" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<claim:ReferenceInfo>
<claim:Provider id="1">
<claim:CommonProviderInfo>
<claim:RegistrationNumber typeOfBody="PCNS">5807824</claim:RegistrationNumber>
<claim:PCNSNumber>5807824</claim:PCNSNumber>
</claim:CommonProviderInfo>
<claim:Name>Mediclinic Morningside</claim:Name>
</claim:Provider>
<claim:Provider id="2">
<claim:CommonProviderInfo>
<claim:RegistrationNumber typeOfBody="HPCSA">0620000323624</claim:RegistrationNumber>
<claim:PCNSNumber>0620000323624</claim:PCNSNumber>
</claim:CommonProviderInfo>
<claim:FullName>
<claim:Initials>none</claim:Initials>
<claim:Surname>DR SULEMAN YF</claim:Surname>
</claim:FullName>
</claim:Provider>
<claim:Diagnosis id="1">
<claim:DiagnosisCode role="PRIMARY" schema="ICD-10" isAuthorisationPrimary="No">K04.6</claim:DiagnosisCode>
<claim:DiagnosisCode role="SECONDARY" schema="ICD-10" isAuthorisationPrimary="No">K08.8</claim:DiagnosisCode>
<claim:DiagnosisCode role="COMORBIDITY" schema="ICD-10" isAuthorisationPrimary="No">E14.9</claim:DiagnosisCode>
<claim:DiagnosisCode role="COMORBIDITY" schema="ICD-10" isAuthorisationPrimary="No">I10</claim:DiagnosisCode>
</claim:Diagnosis>
</claim:ReferenceInfo>
</claim:ProviderClaim>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
                      'http://schemas.phisc.org.za/draft/claim' AS claim
                   )
SELECT x.id.value('@id', 'int') AS id
FROM   @XML.nodes('claim:ProviderClaim/claim:ReferenceInfo/claim:Provider') AS x(id);
```